# How to commit and push Eclipse project to GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, github, commit, egit

I am trying to commit and push a java project from eclipse to github. I cloned the repository using Egit. I did `Team->share Project` to add the project to the repository and the repository icon appeared next to all classes.
However, when I tried to do `Team->add to Index` I could not find `add to Index` option.
Also, I tried to commit and pushed the new classes to the remote repository, but nothing changed in the remote repository.

All changes appear in the `Working Tree` folder, but I am not able to commit and push it to remote repository.

How could I commit and push my project to github?

Comment: First decide whether you're using EGit or Git. You appear to be asking about EGit, so I've dropped the [tag:git] tag, but if you're going to use command line Git instead of EGit, you will want to switch that (but there are no `Team->` clicky things in Git).

Comment: @torek EGit and git-core (the command line Git) are both implementations of Git and the [git] tag is not specific to git-core. For me it is unclear whether this a general Git question that can be answered by explaining Git concepts rather by telling some Git command line commands.

Comment: What exactly did you do in the _Git Staging_ view to push? What push URI do you have configured (in _Git Repositories_ view right-click the push node below _Remotes > origin_ and choose _Configure Push..._)? Did you configured the same SSH key in GitHub and in Eclipse on your local computer?

Comment: I am trying to push the new classes to gitHub. I check push URI it is my gitHub repository. and yes I configured the SHH key. When I do push it says that is up to date. But I have new classes in Eclipse that is not pushed to github. There are no 'Add to Index' option thus the Git Staging is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Team Share project](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#put-project-under-git-version-control) is a local action which will initialize a local repository.

If you have an existing remote repository (on GitHub for instance), you should [clone it with Eclipse](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#exercise-clone-an-existing-repository)

[image: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/img/xegit_import09.png.pagespeed.ic.a9bC-y5Sp2.png]

Then you would *not* need `Team > Share`, and you could start working on file, adding them to the index once they have been modified.

Comment: Yes, I cloned the project with eclipse EGit, but now I would like to add some classes to the gitHub. I see all new classes in the working tree I tried to do add to index, but I cannot see this option in the menu.

Comment: @aga.91 Can you switch to command line, go to the folder of the local repository, type `git status` and `git remote -v`?

Comment: I did both command the status shows all the changes that I made. the remote -v shows the origin 'my github URI'. Is it possible to push to github through the command line?

Comment: If I would like to push to specific brand, not master branch, How could I choose which branch is used in the origin?

Comment: @aga.91 Well done. This is often more reliable.